# How can I remove a node from a circular linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am a beginner in java and I cannot understand linked lists in Java because of their complication. So my code is very simple.

```
Node node, head, tail;
head = null; // initializes the head of the linked list to null
int counter = 0;

String inputdata; // input


do
        {
            System.out.print ("What name would you like stored? (\"quit\" to end) ");
            inputdata = stdin.readLine ();


            if (!inputdata.equals ("quit"))
            {
                node = new Node (inputdata);
                node.next = head;

                // update the head to point to the new front of the list
                head = node;
                count++;
            }
        }
        while (!inputdata.equals ("quit"));  // loop continues until "quit" selected


        System.out.println ();
        node = head;



///////////////////////////////
  String delete;
  boolean found;
  System.out.println ("What node to delete?");
  delete = stdin.readLine ();

 do
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i <= count ; i++)
            {

                if (delete.equals (node.data))
                {
                    found = true;
                    System.out.println ("It is found!");

                }
            }
        }
        while (found = false);
```

This is the class

```
public class Node
{
    Node next;
    String data;

    public Node (String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I understand how the algorithm works. A node is searched and when its found it points the node previous to it to the node after the one being searched.

[image]

Whenever I search for the node I get java.lang.nullpointer exceptions which basically translates into my code is terrible.

I need help because whenever I search how to do this I always ask to myself"why put this" or "what is LS" or "why are there multiple methods and what number are the variables n within it".

Please tell me what Im doing wrong and what I need to do.

Comment: Although this might not be the solution (a solution can't easily be given when we don't know what line the exception occurs at), your search's while loop will only iterate once.  `} while (found = false);` is the equivalent of `found = false; } while (found);`.  Instead, you should check for equivalency: `} while (found == false);`.

Comment: That seems like the easy part. However when allocating the node it seeems rather tricky

Answer (score 0):

```
 node = new Node (inputdata);
            node.next = head;

            // update the head to point to the new front of the list
            head = node;
            count++;
```

1st you make a node, then you say the next one from this node is the head...
and then you go and say thet the head is this node... so you're basically making the head == node == node.next

That just doesn't do :D

I suggest this:

```
    //Init head and tail...
if(head==null){
 head = new Node("Head"); //use whatever data you want/need
 tail= new Node("Tail");
 tail.next=head;
 head.next = tail;
}

//add a new node...
newnode = new Node("Some data");
//since this is a one-way linked list, i suggest you walk from the head
//and go until you meet the tail
currNode = head;
while( currNode.next.data.compareTo("Tail") != 0 )
{
   currNode = currNode.next;
}
//now add the new node here...
newnode.next = currNode.next;
currNode.next = newNode;
```

This way you always add it to the "end" of the list...
If you want to add it at the begining, so just after the head use this:

```
    newNode = new Node("Some data");
    newNode.next = head.next;
    head.next = newNode;
```

It's adviseable that you have a "limiter" like a tail to know when you're at the end of your list...

So now your delete should work, but i recommend a few more things:

```
currentNode = head;
do
    {
        if(currentNode.next.data.compareTo(delete)==0){ //if the next one is the one i'm looking for, remove it and let the garbage collector take care of it
           currentNode.next = currentNode.next.next;
           break; //leave the loop
        else
          currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    while (currentNode.next.data.compareTo("Tail") != 0);
```

With this while loop you'll traverse your list until the end/tail and stop if it wasn't found...
In your example it would go around and around the list for ever, since the searched node wasn't found

Comment: Aw shoot, i forgot to look at the post date :/
Oh well, hope it helps someone in the future..